# Was the double slit experiment tried with slow light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, double-slit-experiment

On wikipedia it is stated that light has been slowed to 17 m/s:

> In 1998, Danish physicist Lene Vestergaard Hau led a combined team from Harvard University and the Rowland Institute for Science which succeeded in slowing a beam of light to about 17 meters per second, and researchers at UC Berkeley slowed the speed of light traveling through a semiconductor to 9.7 kilometers per second in 2004.

I was just wondering if someone has tried the double slit experiment with such slow light.

PS: I understand that the theory says there is no difference, but most new discoveries in physics happen when someone actually tries the theory and sees that it does not hold. My question is strictly whether someone has actually tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of the exact experimental setup you illustrate, but the experiment has been done by passing electrons, one-at-a-time, through a double slit. The single-electron double split experiment was carried out by Stefan Frabboni and coworkers and is mentioned in [this IOP article](https://physicsworld.com/a/double-slits-with-single-atoms/). The predicted interference pattern was observed.

Edit:

————————————————————————————

I was not at all thinking about the actual velocity at which the particles travel through the slit. I was able to access [this article about interferometry with C60 molecules](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.1531580) via my institution to see that there have been experiments with particle velocities as low as 200m/s. This is certainly faster than 17m/s but still well within the non-relativistic regime.

Indeed, the only true answer to the question is whether the exact experiment, described in the question, has been carried out. And I now see why trying to find such a paper is difficult given that Bose-Einstein condensate (BEC) was the medium in [the 1999 experiment](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/haulab/publications/pdf/Slow_Light_1999.pdf) and [BEC interferometry](http://faculty.washington.edu/deepg/BEC%20IFM.shtml) is an active field, but not exactly related to your specific question.

I will update this answer again if time allows, and will not be offended if this answer gets taken down since it does not yet exactly answer the question.

——————————————————————

Comment: I believe the speed of the electrons was much higher than 17 m/s in the experiments you mentioned. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Aha, I now see that the idea is not to slow the rate at which the particles travel through the double slit (which, now that I think about it, might not happen when one slows the photon beam if the slowing of the photons makes them “pile up”), but to reduce the speed at which they pass through the slit. I will edit my response with the lowest speed I could find for a double-slit experiment.

Answer (score 2):

> Was the double slit experiment tried with slow light?

Slow light means that the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) of light is slowed down to the value you give.

The experiments with slowing the velocity are done in an apropirate medium , not in space where the double slit single photon experiment, [for example,](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) is done.

[image: groupphase]

> This shows a wave with the group velocity and phase velocity going in different directions.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) The group velocity is positive (i.e., the envelope of the wave moves rightward), while the phase velocity is negative (i.e., the peaks and troughs move leftward).

The phase velocity of the  " slow" electromagnetic wave is still the constant c.

The mathematics of waves is such, that to go to the trouble of making double slits in a medium  to check whether the group velocity is seen after the slits seems too much trouble. The mathematics would say that yes, there should be an effect of the group velocity on the interference pattern.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the experiment has not been carried out.

Comment: Yes, because the maxwell mathematics has never been falsified so nobody has taken the trouble. Maybe a thesis in a lab where they are studying slow light?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anyone is catching your drift - I think what you're asking is if the effects of the double slit experiment are just the effects of particles (photons) traveling at the speed of light...

As nothing else travels as fast except neutrinos (very hard to detect) we have no idea as to the effects of light speed on the observer...

Even taking a snap-shot (observation) of just one particle - it would still have the observation of the effects of light speed just captured in a moment...

If light speed is the cause of what we see in the double slit experiment - it blows all Quantum Mechanics and its weird unstable world based on observations out of the window...

Comment: The double slit experiment has been done with both massive particles, travelling slower than the speed of light, and with light, travelling at the speed of light. So there is already evidence to falsify the hypothesis that the speed of light is what gives rise to interference. The question seems to be about how extensive such evidence is - what is the slowest speed ever tried.